# Cannot enable pthreads for Netbeans

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, netbeans, pthreads

When I try to use the c++11 thread library in Netbeans (g++ 4.8.2 ubuntu 14.04 LTS) I get the following error:

`##Failure Location unknown## : Error
Test name: Array2DTest::testArray2D
uncaught exception of type std::system_error
- Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted`

I tried enabling pthreads by adding `-pthread` as a additional option for the compilation line as suggested by similar questions and the output seems to show the option is getting passed:

[image]

I've also tried compiling simple "hello world" type tests directly from the terminal and they actually work! For some reason I just can't get netbeans to enable it. The only thing I can think of is I'm trying to test out some multithreading functions in a cppunit test so is it possible this is messing up the pthread option?

**EDIT:**  I found that taking out `pkg-config --libs opencv` results in the `-pthreads` switch working correctly, but I still cant figure out how to get both of them working correctly together.

**EDIT2:**  I was able to get it to compile by removing the `-pthread` switch and inserting `-lpthread` **before** `pkg-config --libs opencv`. The solution only worked by directly linking to the `lpthread` library and it had to be before the opencv libraries. Have no idea why, and it also took me a good 4 hours/blood shot eyes to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was possibly a bug with my version of gcc. The only thing that worked consistently was using the flag:

```
-Wl,--no-as-needed
```

Adding `-pthread` didn't work at all. Adding `-lpthread` made some compilations work, failed for others, and just generally gave strange behavior.